# Ng build on Angular not Works with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have tried to make a test page contain .css inside. First, i embeded css code inside test.component.html, and second i embeded on test.component.ts

Ng serve locally works fine, but when i tried to build with `ng angular --aot` looks css not load anything.

This is my second post, and relate my question before (untill right now i have nothing for the answer of my question). [Ng Build on Angular 6 not Completely Compile my Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853364/ng-build-on-angular-6-not-completely-compile-my-css)

Im trying for the easy study case for using .css in angular, but still can't figure it out, how it can run locally but not at all after build.

local `ng serve` :

[image]

after `ng build --aot` :

[image]

My simple test.content.html:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .text-xxl {
     font-size: 50px;
   }
</style>
<div class="kpi">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of apiData">
        <span class="text-xxl">{{item.total}}</span>
        <span class="text-lg color-gray"> Persons</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

test.component.less :

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styles: [' .text-xxl{ font-size: 50px } .dot{ height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius: 100%; display: inline-block; } .dot-red { background-color: #ff0000; } .dot-green { background-color: #008000; } .dot-yellow { background-color: #ffff00; }'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: does ng serve --aot produce the required result .?

Comment: ng serve produce required result, as i expected. @FranklinPious

Comment: did u try serving in aot ? ie  ng serve --aot

Comment: yup, i tried ng serve --aot. and it works fine

Comment: check whether the configurations are correct in the build section in angular.json file?